# automating a repetitive task in setting network connectivity

Tags: windows, networking, registry, settings, tcp

The purpose of this question is which programing language would be best suited for accomplishing this and is their a program that could do this for me? Often times I have to setup a static IP address, netmask, gateway DNSs and DNS suffixes for Windows that are created as a vm through vsphere. All this information I'm typing in is always the same except for the static IP address. I'm working with any version of Windows from XP to 8 (including server builds). Is there anyway I can simplify or automate part of my task? As it is I can't even copy and paste a list of suffixes as Windows makes you input one at a time. Would a language such as Power Shell or using .bat files be helpful? Would it be enough exporting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters` from a working computer and inserting it to the new builds registry?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the static adress with:

```
netsh interface ip set address "lanname" static %IP_Addr% %Sub_Mask% %D_Gate% 1
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the inputs are, for example where does the ip address go, `%IP_Addr%`?

Comment: Look in your network sharing center for interface name. So  with default windows interface would look for example as follows: **netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 123.123.123.123 255.255.255.0 123.123.123.1** the command has a help inbuilt and you can find more info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx